# How to allow a button to stop an action AND have that action affect form controls

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

So basically, I'm creating music software and would like the ability to pause/stop the song whenever necessary. However, when the song is playing it doesn't allow any controls on the form to be used and the "KeyDown" event also seems unaffective, therefore I can't stop the song until it's over.

I've tried using an instance of the "thread" class to do this but the problem is that I require the use of certain "Label" controls on the form, which seems to be hard to do from another thread.

Here's the gist of my "playing" code.

```
        Sound[] notes = song.Sounds;
        double seconds = 0;
        foreach (Sound sound in notes)
        {
            seconds += (double)sound.NoteType.GetDuration(tempo) / 1000;
        }
        timeleft = seconds;
        lblSecondsLeft.Text = timeleft + "";
        double length = notes.Length;
        double thing = (100 / length);
        double otherthing = Math.Round(thing);
        sounds = notes;
        double progress = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.Length; i++)
        {
            Sound sound = notes[i];
            lblTempo.Text = tempo.ToString();
            string note = sound.Note.ToString();
            lblNote.Text = note;
            progress += thing;
            lblProgress.Text = progress + "%";
            seconds -= (double)sound.NoteType.GetDuration(tempo) / 1000;
            lblSecondsLeft.Text = seconds + " seconds left";
            sound.PlaySound(song.Channel);
        }
```

Comment: Well, you're running everything synchronously on the UI thread - of course the UI can't be used. Is there an asynchronous API for the `Sound` class (whatever that is)? Playing note-by-note probably isn't going to work very well anyway, though...

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I attempted to run this code in another thread before, therefore it was already asynchronous.

Comment: Hm, you wont get away from using different threads. But accessing controls from another thread is no problem if you use Invoke.

Comment: Well, the easiest way is to separate your presentation code from the actual playback. Then you can just use e.g. `IProgress<T>` to post any UI updates as necessary. Though you might want to use a pull-based approach instead anyway, since your curent approach is either issuing too many updates (when notes are short) or too few (when notes are long). A timer reading current state and updating the UI would probably work better.

Comment: Adding to @Luaan last comment you can add event `NextNote` to update progress (e.g. displaying currently played note and how many notes/seconds has left) and events `Started`/`Finished` (for obvious reasons) to your model (used to play song).

Answer (score 0):

It's an annoyance, but it's a well known annoyance. You have to run the non-UI code on a separate (non-UI) thread so that the UI stays responsive to buttons and text updates and whatnot. However, this means that you have to update the UI from the non-UI thread by switching to the UI thread during the update. The following code does this.

Note 1: This is trimmed from some code I have to hand, so it's not properly checked.

Note 2: This is a WPF version, WinForms is slightly different but the principle is identical.

```
   public String LabelText{
        get {
            if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
                return (String)this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Func<String>(() => { return LabelText; }));
            }
            return Label.Text;
        }
        set {
            if (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { LabelText = value; }));
                return;
            }
            LabelText = value;
        }
    }
```

This works by checking to see if get/set is on the right thread, if it's not then it switches thread and calls itself (now on the correct thread), completes the get or set and returns. You can also use BeginInvoke if you don't need the thread to wait for the screen update, which for real time music may well be the case.

Comment: Further note to this one, for some curious reason CheckAccess does not appear as a method of Dispatcher in Intellisense, you just have to assume it exists and all is well.